# Split by "pipeline" with a negative lookahead/lookbehind

Tags: python, split, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I have this code:

```
my_string = "(chargeur|magn(e|é)tique) sans fil|chargeur solaire (imperm(e|é)able|pliable)|chargeur ext(e|é)rieur externe|chargeur de t(e|é)l(e|é)phone solaire"
my_list = re.split(r'\|\s*(?![^()]*\))', my_string)
print(my_list)
```

I am trying to split by pipeline but also take in consideration the parenthesis. For exemple my list should be something like this:
my_list = ['(chargeur|magn(e|é)tique) sans fil', 'chargeur solaire (imperm(e|é)able|pliable)' etc..]

But instead I get this:
my_list = ['(chargeur', 'magn(e|é)tique) sans fil', 'chargeur solaire (imperm(e|é)able|pliable)' etc..]

I know there is a lookahead and lookbehind negative approach, but I don't really understand how should I merge them in order to consider all the parenthesis. Thank you!

Comment: So only split on pipes outside of parentheses?

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So all the parenthesis that are in the text are balanced? Can you make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead of `re`?

Comment: Yes they are all balanced. I honestly prefer not to change or add another library, unless it's really necessary, the rest of my code is based on the "re" library and that would mean to rethink all the code.

Comment: @alinapal you could use it like `import regex as re` See [this example](https://tio.run/##RY9RasMwDIbffQrRJ6kphbK3QukNdoF2A69VEkPseLICHfhCO8cOlrl1Sv2iX/yfpV/xR/sxvM2z83EUBeGOb2BTEcZEq8oS4ACywuP@9JmRPtZ4xkdTdNNkPO6I1meixaUmV9WsjEnl6wovvZWOJ8nedgE5//2Suu@JCZINCVo35CcCaRysEwYseVh8pe3XwDkO7l7pxfJNqy9uaUtYfvlXhgUYaonlVH6uKPG81UvP95DC29aFqysTcLl6A4mMaUeBB/Y@@U1V4AJwmDyLVcZlRqHVih52tDdQXhQXtJrbTsYpItE8/wM)

Comment: ohh didn't knew that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution:

```
def split_string(string):
    result = []
    current = []
    level = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == "(":
            level += 1
        elif char == ")":
            level -= 1
        if char == "|" and level == 0:
            result.append("".join(current))
            current = []
            continue
         current.append(char)
    result.append("".join(current))
    return result
my_string = "(chargeur|magn(e|é)tique) sans fil|chargeur solaire (imperm(e|é)able|pliable)|chargeur ext(e|é)rieur externe|chargeur de t(e|é)l(e|é)phone solaire"
my_list = split_string(my_string)
print(my_list)
```

The code uses a counter level to keep track of the level of parentheses. Whenever a left parenthesis is encountered, the level is increased, and whenever a right parenthesis is encountered, the level is decreased. The pipeline is split only when the level is 0, meaning that the pipeline is not between any parentheses.